# Send data back to React client from Node server with POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post

A very simple counter application using React and Nodejs. In the client side, I have a counter component which consists of a count state and rendering on the UI with default value of 0 and each time user presses the increment button, it'll trigger a POST request API to node server. Then node server will then process the request and respond to the client with its result. How would I accomplish this?

Client side (Counter component)

```
this.state = {
   count : 0
}

sendAPI() {
   axios.post('http://localhost:3001/increment', this.state.count)...
}

render() {
    <div>
        <button onClick = {this.sendAPI()} type="button">increment</button>
        Counter: {this.state.count}  
    </div>
}
```

Server side (express server)

```
app.post('/increment', function(req,res) {
     res.send(req.body.count + 1)
}
```

How do I res.send() data back to "this.state.count" on the client side?

Comment: On the axios Ajax query there should be a "complete" or "callback" or "then" function. Right there you will receive the data you sent with `res.send()`. I recommend you to check axios documentation on that. Just search `axios post` on Google and you will see a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the button `onClick` don't call the function, but pass the function as a reference.

```
state = {
   count : 0
}

sendAPI() {
   axios.post('http://localhost:3001/increment', {count: this.state.count})
       .then(res => {
               const count = res.data;
               this.setState({count: +count})
           );
}

render() {
    <div>
        <button onClick = {this.sendAPI} type="button">increment</button>
        Counter: {this.state.count}  
    </div>
}
```

Server side (express server)

```
app.post('/increment', function(req,res) {
     res.send(+req.body.count + 1)
}
```